# How to parse date time based on LCID/locale using angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Usually I will be getting the date value from DB as 05/21/2000(en-Us) but sometimes I am getting value as "21-05-2000" and it's locale is en-In. I have to parse this date based on the locale and format them to a different Date format.

Comment: you should be getting the locale from using the locale by using the method [**getLocaleDateTimeFormat**](https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleDateTimeFormat) method Read [**Date Pipe Guide**](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#how-to-use)

Comment: I couldn't form the date object using the content which I am getting.. if I can able to form a date object I can able to use the Date Pipe as you said. My question is how can I parse the existing date using the LCID or locale information. In C# we can do this using parseexact method.